# Block http traffic

Tags: help, https

I configured a hidden service and it works. But when i type the IP into a regular browser, the same web page is hosted from the apache server.

How do i prevent it from serving the http content and only serve the onion content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the server from being accessible from the network, you need to bind your webserver to localhost rather than to all interfaces. So for example in your apache config, instead of:

```
Listen 80
```

You need:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Brilliant that sorted it! Thank you